# Get Database names of SQL Server in remote machine with in network

Tags: sql-server, powershell, inno-setup, regedit

I am using `inno` setup to install `SQL Server with Database` and `Wildfly` in two different machines (Machine A and Machine B) in a network respectively.

1. As a first step, I install any one `SQL Server (2012, 2014 or 2016 versions)` in Machine A.
2. In second step, I install `Wildfly 10` in Machine B and during the installation I have a page where the user inputs the name of Database Server name, Database name and Instance name.

In order to verify the above entries, I have to validate that the Database name and Instance name is available in the Database server.

I was able to connect to the registry of the remote Machine B from Machine A to get the instance name installed using Power shell command with the below query

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName MachineB -Command {Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL'}
```

However, I could not find the list of databases installed in the registry.
Is there any way to get the list of databases available in the machine so that I can validate the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sql Server does not store database names in the registry. Query [`sys.databases`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql) for db names. Like so,

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance myServer\myInstance -Query "select name from sys.databases"
```

In order to use `Invoke-SqlCmd` on a system that doesn't have Sql Server installed, install Sql Server [Powershell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module) to the local system.

Comment: the above query works like a charm if I execute it in the same machine. But from my remote machine, it throws "The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet" error. Do I need SQL Server 2014 and above to use this query?

Comment: @DeeJay007 No, you need to install Sql Server [Powershell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module) to the local system.

Comment: I am trying to install SQL Server Powershell module and as a requirement, I have installed NuGetProvider. But when I follow the further steps and execute the command "Get-PSRepository", I am getting "WARNING: Unable to find module repositories." warning and I am stuck. Am unable to pass this issue to install the same.

Comment: @DeeJay007 Please post another a question about how to install Powershell modules.

Comment: Okay sure @vonPryz